# UnityEngin.UI "Error CS0103: The name "Text" does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm just trying to use method `.text` 
But it's like if `UnityEngine.UI` doesn't load
I'v checked the references in the solution panel. And `UnityEngine.UI` is there. So I don't know what's wrong.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class NW : MonoBehaviour {

// Use this for initialization
public Text text;

}
```

Comment: are you using Unity 4.6 or higher?

Comment: save the script. close Mono/VS. Save the project. close Unity and restart it

Comment: err, shouldn't it read `public Text text(){`? Do you want `text` to be a method or an attribute of NW?